# Java: variable decimal length formatted output

Tags: java, printf, formatted-text

Let a be any floating point number:

```
float a = 13.1234567;
```

then I get a decimal places length from standard input:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int decLen = sc.nextInt();
```

How do I print 'a' with 'decLen' decimal places after the point?
I need to print for

decLen = 3:

```
13.123
```

decLen = 6:

```
13.123456
```

decLen = 0:

```
13
```

Is there in the Java libaries any formatting method capable of this kind of tasks?

Comment: It is not a duplicate.  This question deals with the scale of a primitive and the other formatting a number to a given scale.

Answer (score -1):

A bit of a hack, but this will work:

```
    double[] doubles = {13.123, 13.123456, 13};
    for (int i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++) {
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(doubles[i]));
        System.out.println("decLen = " + bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros().scale());
    };
```

prints:

```
decLen = 3
decLen = 6
decLen = 0
```

Converting the float or double to a string will prevent rounding errors when creating the BigDecimal.

Comment: This is not answering _"How do I print 'a' with 'decLen' decimal places after the point?"_